# Get latest record in MySQL

Tags: mysql, max

I have this table with employee contract records.

```
+----+---------------------------+
| id | start| end     | employee |
+----+---------------------------+
|  8 | 2016 | 2017    | 777      |
|  7 | 2014 | 2015    | 777      |
|  6 | 2012 | 2013    | 777      |
|  5 | 2010 | 2011    | 777      |
|  3 | 2016 | 2017    | 666      |
|  4 | 2014 | 2015    | 666      |
|  2 | 2012 | 2013    | 666      |
|  1 | 2010 | 2011    | 666      |
+----+---------------------------+
```

I'm having difficulty getting the latest contract per employee.

The query should print:

```
+----+-----------------+
| id | start| employee |
+----+-----------------+
|  8 | 2016 | 777      |
|  3 | 2016 | 666      |
+----+-----------------+
```

I have tried so far:

```
SELECT 
MAX(start)
,id
,employee
FROM contract
GROUP BY employee
```

but that gives me **id** that doesn't correspond to the record.

Comment: This is a common question for mysql and group by
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `group by` for this.   You want to filter the rows, so use `where` -- in this case with a subquery of some sort.

Here is one method:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contract c
WHERE c.id (SELECT MAX(c2.id)
            FROM contract c2
            WHERE c2.employee = c.employee
           );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
WHERE t.start in (SELECT MAX(t2.start)
            FROM test t2
            group by t2.employee
           );
```

and SQLFiddle [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53749/1)

Answer (score 1):

**CREATE table/insert data**

```
CREATE TABLE contract
    (`id` INT, `start` INT, `end` INT, `employee` INT)
;

INSERT INTO contract
    (`id`, `start`, `end`, `employee`)
VALUES
    (8, 2016, 2017, 777),
    (7, 2014, 2015, 777),
    (6, 2012, 2013, 777),
    (5, 2010, 2011, 777),
    (3, 2016, 2017, 666),
    (4, 2014, 2015, 666),
    (2, 2012, 2013, 666),
    (1, 2010, 2011, 666)
;
```

Use user variables to mark the greatest price off every grouped employee.

**User variables query**

```
SELECT
     contract.id
   , contract.start
   , contract.employee
   , (contract.employee != @employee) AS employeeMax -- Mark a new employee as Max
   , (@employee := contract.employee) AS employeeInit
  FROM
   contract
  ORDER BY
      contract.employee 
    , contract.start DESC -- DESC for MAX(start) ASC for MIN(start)
```

**Result**

```
    id   start  employee  employeeMax  employeeInit  
------  ------  --------  -----------  --------------
     3    2016       666            1             666
     4    2014       666            0             666
     2    2012       666            0             666
     1    2010       666            0             666
     8    2016       777            1             777
     7    2014       777            0             777
     6    2012       777            0             777
     5    2010       777            0             777
```

**Complete Query**

Now filter on employeeMax = 1 to only keep the greatest price records like so.

```
SELECT
   contract_group.id
 , contract_group.start
 , contract_group.employee
FROM (
  SELECT
     contract.id
   , contract.start
   , contract.employee
   , (contract.employee != @employee) AS employeeMax -- Mark a new employee as Max
   , (@employee := contract.employee) AS employeeInit
  FROM
   contract
  ORDER BY
      contract.employee 
    , contract.start DESC -- DESC for MAX(start) ASC for MIN(start)
)
 AS
   contract_group
WHERE
 contract_group.employeeMax = 1 -- keep only the employee max marked records
```

**Result**

```
    id   start  employee  
------  ------  ----------
     3    2016         666
     8    2016         777
```